# Convert any DateTime string format to US short date "MM-dd-yyyy"

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I am trying here to write a generalized code to convert any provided valid `date` / `datetime` formatto **US short date format**.

Below is the code I am trying:

```
public static string ConvertToUSDateFormat(string dateString)
{
      string[] formats = {"dd/MM/yyyy", "dd-MMM-yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd","yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:tt", "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:tt", "M/d/yyyy", "dd MMM yyyy","dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:tt", "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:tt", "dd-MM-yyyy h:mm:tt"};
      string convertedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
      return convertedDate;
}
```

The **input** I am providing to this method is **`19-01-2018 10:55:52`**.

But this code is throwing an error: **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Comment: You should try with `ss`, not `tt`. `ss` is for seconds, `tt` is for.. well, whatever the AM/PM thing is called. Having said that, I don't think your solution is very reliable, you should really have some way of knowing the exact format of your input to ensure you can parse it correctly

Comment: I think `InvariantCulture` requires an ISO timestamp?

Comment: @musefan: That worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"19-01-2018 10:55:52"
```

Match with the below format which does not exist in the formats array.

```
"dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"
```